# Does linker exist in all compiled programming languages?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker

It does exist in C/C++, but I'm not sure about any other programming languages. I'm just curious if linker exist in all compiled programming languages or does every language creator decide how the code gets compiled ?

For Benj: I mean native languages, no managed code like CLR.

Comment: Any language which supports libraries will have a linker of some sort whether it be at compile time or run/jit time.

Comment: When you say "compiled" are you including managed languages?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "a linker". Are you asking if a standalone tool called "a linker" exists? Or whether something exists which does the job of a linker?  Does it have to be a tool that runs at compile-time? And so on. If you define it broadly enough, every compiled language needs something to link different modules together to create an executable program. But the details vary. It might be a standalone tool, it might be a phase in the compiler, it might be something that's done by the language runtime when the program is loaded or executed.

Comment: Examples of where a standalone linker doesn't exist or is at least not the common path to an executable are Delphi or FPC on Windows. Both have the linker integrated into the compiler, which also features an autobuild system to build multiple compilation units in one go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a linker is not part of a language, but part of an implementation of a language. (Also, languages are not inherently "compiled" or "interpreted" -- these are both features of an implementation too).

Linkers allow language implementers to implement "separate compilation". Separate compilation is a feature which is quite important for allowing physical decoupling of separate parts of a program and for allowing partial builds (which can reduce total build times). For this reason, most implementations of languages which output native binaries will use a linker as part of their implementation.

That said, a linker is not a *required* part of a compiling implementation of a language, and it is possible to imagine that some language implementations would not use linker (consider a student project to write a language and implement it -- if this language was not expected to be used with any large programs, the time spent to implement/integrate a linker might be deemed not worthwhile).

Comment: Linkers also allow heterogeneous applications which include modules written in multiple languages.

Comment: I agree with what you write, but how could one practically implement C language by the standard without having a linker? My imagination is too limited to see it before me :)

Answer (score 3):

Java, for instance, does not (strictly speaking) have a tool called a "linker", but it has a similar concept.

Fundamentally, if your executable code is built of disjoint object files (or equivalent), then there must always be *something* that pulls them together by the time they need to be run.

Comment: The JLS does identify linking as one phase in program execution though.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are many compiled languages that do not use a linker. For example Forth, Lisp and to some extent Java do not need it.

The same work (letting different compilation units know about each other) still needs to be done, but that can be done by other means than having a link step. For example, look-up can be done in runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, there have been some compiled languages which did not use any sort of linking.  Perhaps the most famous was Turbo Pascal, which in its earliest versions (prior to 4.0) made a single pass through the source file (or source files, if the `{$I filename}` directive was used), generating output code directly, and building up a fixup list (I think fixups were applied to the written object file after other compilation was complete, since the compiler ran decently even with a floppy drive as the destination).

Comment: "Standard" Pascal didn't (and still doesn't?) support separate compilation.  Which raises the issue of what one means by "linking".  (On the other hand, even languages like Turbo Pascal must "link" in some of the system interface.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Turbo Pascal didn't "link" in the system interface via any sort of linker step.  It simply IIRC copied the first 10K of the compiler executable at the start of any .COM file it produced (unless instructed to produce a ".chn" file, which was basically an executable minus the first 10k, and which could only be run by being "chained" from another compiled executable).

Answer (score 1):

Define what you mean by "linker".  Anytime there is separate compilation, there must be a step somewhere which "links" whatever the compilation output.  If you consider "linking" just filling in addresses in otherwise compiled object code, however (what traditional linkers do), then a lot of more modern systems don't "link".  The output of the compiler will be some intermediate format, and the final step will put this together into a single entity before generating the machine code from it.

All of this, of course, ignores the issues of dynamic linking and just in time compilation, which further fogs the issues.

So about all you can say is that for a sufficiently vague definition of linking, all languages with separate compilation support it, and for a sufficiently strict version, a lot of modern compilers don't "link" for any language.